# Selecting data from mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using this to select data from mysql in php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "******";
$password = "******";
$database = "*******";

// Create connection
$conn2 = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
$stmt = $conn2->prepare('SELECT id, title, views from `blog_main`');

$stmt->execute();
var_dump($stmt);

$result = $stmt->get_result();
 while($r=$result->fetch_assoc())
{
        echo "id: " . $r["id"]. " - Name: " . $r["title"]. " " . $r["views"]. "<br>";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

However no result is shown, but if I run this query on phpmyadmin interface it returns rows.
This code worked fine on localhost but when I shifted it to godaddy's server, I'm facing this problem only in prepared statement.
When I'm using normal query method it displays rows, only prepared statements are not working.

This is the value of var dump:

```
object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (10) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(-1) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(3) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(1) }
```

Is there any kind of extension I need to enable or what might be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this is neither a tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can help solve [certain problems](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's **your** job to [put some efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in the first place, incl. elementary [(re)search](https://google.com/). Majority of newbies' questions are not unique and has already been answered multiple times.

Comment: @Marcin exactly! I've showed my codes and efforts I already made. Please provide me the link where this question has been answered multiple times. I've already researched and tried.

Comment: So if you do `conn2->query()` (and comment out `execute`) it works?

Comment: @chris85 no, also when I var_dump it before executing it gives out the same thing as I've mentioned above. Num rows:0 , field count:3

Comment: You might want to rephrase this than `I'm facing this problem only in prepared statement` because it sounds like executing as unprepared also fails. You are accessing the same DB?

Comment: Yes. It's the same db

Answer (score 0):

here is my answer for your question,

create file db.php

```
$dbInfo = array(
    'host'      => "localhost",
    'user'      => "******",
    'pass'      => "******",
    'dbname'    => "******"
);
```

create dbcon.php

```
class database{
    protected $databaseLink;
    function __construct(){
        include "db.php";
        $this->database = $dbInfo['host'];
        $this->mysql_user = $dbInfo['user'];
        $this->mysql_pass = $dbInfo['pass'];
        $this->databaseName = $dbInfo['dbname'];
        $this->openConnection();
        return $this->get_link();
    }
    function openConnection(){
    $this->databaseLink = mysqli_connect($this->database, $this->mysql_user, $this->mysql_pass, $this->databaseName);
    }

    function get_link(){
    return $this->databaseLink;
    }
}
```

create func.php

```
include "dbcon.php";

function selectData(){
        $db = new database();
        $selectQuery = "SELECT id, title, views FROM blog_main";
        $selectQuery = mysqli_query($db->get_link(), $selectQuery) or die(mysqli_error());
        while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectQuery)) {
            $rows[] = $r;
        }
        return $result = json_encode(($rows));
        mysqli_close($db->get_link());
     }
```

and in for example index.php you can get data from which SQL return

```
include "func.php";
$data = selectData();


$dataJson = json_decode($data, TRUE);

foreach ($dataJson as $key => $value) {
    echo "id: " . $value['id']. " - Name: " . $value['title']. " " . $value['views']. "<br>";
}
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it was the disable driver issue. I enabled the stmt_mysqli driver and it worked.